# Why is important to reopen a connection to mysql?

Tags: php, mysql

I have seen programmers that to this in the same doc:

```
$connection = mysql_connect("localhost","user","password");
        $request = "firts request";
        mysql_query( $request , $connection );
        mysql_close( $conexion );
$connection = mysql_connect("localhost","user","password");
        $request = "second request";
        mysql_query( $request , $connection );
        mysql_close( $conexion );
```

The question is what if I do not close the connection?

Comment: it's not important. a lot of people simply follow the cargo-cult paradigm. about the only time you'd need to open multiple connections is if you need to use different credentials on two+ simultaneous connections

Comment: fixed typos (enable spell checker), removed 'thanks' (noise), edited title for readability

Comment: thank you, then is just particular usei can do this or ot, is my choice. rigth?

Comment: Year is 2015. Please use PDO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First! It is time to use the mysqli_* functions over mysql_*. [**Why?**](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php)

**About open connection each time...**

Remember that database connections take "time" to create, normally you have the database on different hardware than your web solution. This means each connection will involve network exchange and this is expensive in a solution with high load of users/multiple connections. From my "world" we normally use some connection patterns to reuse the connections created using some connection pool. From a database connection pool we reuse the amount connections the exist, we can increase and tune this depends on the enterprise. Now for php you should check the mysqli and p: to achieve similar functionality, see [***persistent connections***](http://www.php.net/manual/de/mysqli.construct.php)

> Prepending host by p: opens a persistent connection. mysqli_change_user() is automatically called on connections opened from the connection pool.

**Regarding closing the connection**, the spec [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.close.php)

> Open connections (and similar resources) are automatically destroyed at the end of script execution. However, you should still close or free all connections, result sets and statement handles as soon as they are no longer required. This will help return resources to PHP and MySQL faster.

And if you work on new php application you might also consider start with PDO, mysql_ is easier to migrate to mysqli_ but if this is totally new you really should check PDO. Which will also give you the persistent connection functionallity. Read more at [Api choosing](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php), [Library choosing](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.library.choosing.php) and [PDO connections](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.connections.php)

Comment: Yes, but what really helped thank you MrSimpleMind, I have seen video tutorials where I open a connection and an application then closes the connection and open again the same connection to another query ... is the same connection. why close and reopen?

Comment: It depends on the code, the programmer, etc. Some does always open, process and close all the time. It is a habit an to be sure that the update for example is done. I would say keep your connection open as long as you need it (but be reasonable here!), and close it at end. This will help you alot, not only in the php world. You maybe can share the code you are working on, and take more input about it? It is easier to discuss it when we see the code. Good luck my friend.

Comment: and regarding `what if you dont close` as given in the question, well .. nothing will happen. The close will be performed when your php page has been executed to end anyway. Lot of ppl do open, process, close always as said just of habit and to keep them visible together. It makes it easier for them to follow the code, instead of scroll up and see where the connection opened, in what function, and when was it close etc. Hope you understand my point.

Answer (score 0):

The idea about closing the connection is to handle resources properly. An open connection is consuming some resources on the server.

Also, it can be a security issue to leave a connection open. Anyway as in any other case you should find a balance between the two positions based on how your specific code is working.

My answer works for any connection library you use but **note that mysql_ is deprecated and will be soon removed**. Consider using myslqi_ or better start using PDO